# How to use delegates in my controller to refactor code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

In my project I am declaring instance variable with the help of `before_action` callback, but some of my controllers have same callback code. ex:

my `golf_courses_users_controller.rb` looks like:

```
private
    def require_user_club_and_golf_course
      @club_admin_user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])
      @golf_course = GolfCourse.find(params[:golf_course_id])
    end
```

my `course_holes_controller.rb` looks like:

```
private
    def initialize_objects
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])
      @golf_course = GolfCourse.find(params[:golf_course_id])
    end
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you want to dry it?

Comment: yes I want to DRY the code across different controllers

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to set this up is to have the method assigning the instance variables in a parent class (for the sake of simplicity, I'll use `ApplicationController` here), and then call the `before_action` in the relevant controllers.

**application_controller.rb**

```
def initialize_objects
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])
  @golf_course = GolfCourse.find(params[:golf_course_id])
end
```

**golf_courses_users_controller.rb**

```
before_action :initialize_objects
```

**course_holes_controller.rb**

```
before_action :initialize_objects
```

Depending on how widespread the use of this before action will be, you could even move the `before_action` to the same parent controller, and skip this where not needed:

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_action :initialize_objects
```

**a_controller_not_using_the_before_action.rb**

```
skip_before_action :initialize_objects
```

That seems dry, clean and pretty conventional to me - let me know what you think and if you have any questions.

Comment: Did this help at all @PujanSoni?

Answer (score 0):

I would produce a helper and use it everywhere:

```
module DbHelper do
  def self.user_club_course(params)
    # maybe raise unless
    #   params.values_at(*%i[user_id club_id golf_course_id]).none?(&:nil?)
    [
      User.find(params[:user_id]),
      Club.find(params[:club_id]),
      GolfCourse.find(params[:golf_course_id])
    ]
  end
end
```

And use it like:

```
@user, @club, @golf_course = DbHelper.user_club_course(params)
```